# Conditions based in date periods and groups

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

```
            A    B           C   D
0  2002-01-13  Dan  2002-01-15  10
1  2002-01-13  Dan  2002-01-25  24
2  2002-01-13  Vic  2002-01-17  14
3  2002-01-13  Vic  2002-01-03  18
4  2002-01-28  Mel  2002-02-08  37
5  2002-01-28  Mel  2002-02-06  29
6  2002-01-28  Mel  2002-02-10  20
7  2002-01-28  Rob  2002-02-12  30
8  2002-01-28  Rob  2002-02-01  47
```

I want to create a new `df['E']` column, with next conditions, per each `B` group:

- E=D value, where `A` dates are nearest to 10 days later than `C` date.
- If there are two `C` dates at the same distance to 10 days from `A` (case of `2002-01-28` `Mel`), `E` will be the mean of these same-period `D` values.

Output should be:

```
            A    B           C   D   E
0  2002-01-13  Dan  2002-01-15  10  24
1  2002-01-13  Dan  2002-01-25  24  24
2  2002-01-13  Vic  2002-01-17  14  14
3  2002-01-13  Vic  2002-01-03  18  14
4  2002-01-28  Mel  2002-02-08  37  33
5  2002-01-28  Mel  2002-02-06  29  33
6  2002-01-28  Mel  2002-02-10  20  33
7  2002-01-28  Rob  2002-02-12  30  30 
8  2002-01-28  Rob  2002-02-01  47  30
```

Comment: Do you have thresh for how near is near ? , for me all Mel should be consider near

Comment: 2002-01-28 + 10 days = 2002-02-07. There is not just one nearest value to 2002-02-07 in Mel group, but there are two dates at the same distance, 2002-02-08 and 2002-02-06. In this case, E value is D mean in these rows, this is (37+29)/2=33

Comment: I got you , and adding a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok , seems you need

```
df['E']=abs((df.C-df.A).dt.days-10)# get the days different 
df['E']=df.B.map(df.loc[df.E==df.groupby('B').E.transform('min')].groupby('B').D.mean())# find the min value for the different , and get the mean 
df
Out[106]: 
           A    B          C   D   E
0 2002-01-13  Dan 2002-01-15  10  24
1 2002-01-13  Dan 2002-01-25  24  24
2 2002-01-13  Vic 2002-01-17  14  14
3 2002-01-13  Vic 2002-01-03  18  14
4 2002-01-28  Mel 2002-02-08  37  33
5 2002-01-28  Mel 2002-02-06  29  33
6 2002-01-28  Mel 2002-02-10  20  33
7 2002-01-28  Rob 2002-02-12  30  30
8 2002-01-28  Rob 2002-02-01  47  30
```